# Why does MySQL Connector/J throw java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested?

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector

Why does the following code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE foo (name VARCHAR(30))");
ps.executeUpdate(); // or ps.execute();
ps.getGeneratedKeys(); // <-- throws an exception
```

throw this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate(), Statement.executeLargeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().
```

---

Correct me if I am wrong, but neither [`java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html) API Specification nor [JDBC 4.3 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) (specifically, section 13.6) specifies such behaviour. Where does it *explicitly* say in the specification documents what the exception message commands the user to do?

All I could find was this:

> If this `Statement` object did not generate any keys, an empty `ResultSet`
>   object is returned. *[Source: [`getGeneratedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) Javadoc]*

I was expecting an empty `ResultSet` instead of an exception.

Comment: If you have not seen it already: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1382309_1.html

Comment: In other words, use `con.prepareStatement("...", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);`, explicitly saying that generated keys should be made available for retrieval.

Comment: @PM77-1 My *Why* was a different kind. I claim that the exception violates the javadoc specification.

Comment: There are no generated keys after a CREATE TABLE statement. Your code doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @user207421 I'm aware of that. But if, for example, you run the same snippet with PostgreSQL JDBC driver on a Postgre database, it does in fact return an empty `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 4):

> Correct me if I am wrong, but the Java SQL api docs do not specify such behaviour. Where does it *explicitly* say in the Javadocs what the error message commands the user to do?

It doesn't say it *explicitly*, but it does say it *implicitly*.

There are 6 overloads to [`prepareStatement​`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#i31), the first two are:

- [`prepareStatement​(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)): Creates a `PreparedStatement` object for sending parameterized SQL statements to the database.
- [`prepareStatement​(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,int)): Creates a default `PreparedStatement` object **that has the capability to retrieve auto-generated keys**.

*Implied* in the description of the second one, is that if you don't ask for it, the `PreparedStatement` will not have the capability to retrieve auto-generated keys.

Whether the driver enforces this is entirely up to the driver and how the given database implements retrieval of auto-generated keys.

Some databases requires modifying the `INSERT` statement, e.g. to add a `RETURNING` clause for returning the generated key values. I believe *Oracle Database* works like that, in order to obtain the key value that was assigned by a `TRIGGER`. If you don't tell the `PreparedStatement` to modify the `INSERT` statement before the statement is executed, the values won't be available for `getGeneratedKeys` to retrieve. Actually, for Oracle Database to work, I believe you need to call the [`prepareStatement​(String sql, String[] columnNames)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method, naming the columns you need returned, so the driver can build the `RETURNING` clause.

Other databases, e.g. *SQL Server*, can retrieve the auto-generated key by executing a statement like `SELECT @@IDENTITY` *after* the `INSERT` statement. As such, they don't need to modify the `INSERT` statement, and can therefore do it on-demand when the `getGeneratedKeys` method is called. Might still be better for performance to do it up-front, to save a round-trip to the database.

> *From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507684/why-does-mysql-connector-j-throw-java-sql-sqlexception-generated-keys-not-reque#comment105188126_59507684):* I claim that the exception violates the javadoc specification.

It does not. Just because the javadoc of one of the overloads don't explicitly say that generated keys will not be available, it doesn't mean that you shouldn't consider the overloads and why they are there, i.e. what features they enable and that those features are not enabled if not explicitly requested by you by calling the correct overload.

It's not a violation, though I agree that it would be nice for the javadoc to be more explicit.

---

**UPDATE:** More on the exception being perceived as a violation of the API.

The exception is not the driver violating the API, since [`getGeneratedKeys`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) is only expected to work if it has been *enabled*. Calling `getGeneratedKeys` without enabling it is *you* violating the API, so it is appropriate for the driver to reject that call (but not required that it does).

There is a difference between having `getGeneratedKeys` enabled and having the SQL statement actually generating keys. E.g. following are examples of SQL statements that don't generate a key:

- `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.
- `INSERT INTO x (...) SELECT ... FROM ...` statement *can* generate keys, but if the `SELECT` doesn't return any rows, then the `INSERT` doesn't generate any keys.

If `getGeneratedKeys` has been *enabled*, the API spec says that it must return an empty `ResultSet` object for those kinds of statements.

Comment: I can accept your answer in the case where you actually expect a statement to generate auto-generated keys. But if you do not, and if you did not specify that you wish for any, I believe that `getGeneratedKeys()` should humbly return an empty `ResultSet` because according to its javadoc the exception should only be thrown  *if a database access error occurs or this method[`getGeneratedKeys()`] is called on a closed `Statement`*.

Comment: @JanezKuhar - If you believe the JDBC specification, API documentation, or a specific implementation to be **incorrect**, you should submit a bug report.

Comment: @JanezKuhar In addition to the javadoc, there is also a [JDBC specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html).  Retrieval of generated keys is covered in section 13.6 of the JDBC 4.3 specification.  All code examples in that section specify either RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS or an array of generated key columns.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the link. I've read the section before posting this question. But as I've said in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507684/why-does-mysql-connector-j-throw-java-sql-sqlexception-generated-keys-not-reque/59507828?noredirect=1#comment105188466_59507828), the examples only cover the *positive* case.

Comment: @VGR and Andreas, the JDBC API doc says on [`getGeneratedKeys`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys--): _"If this `Statement` object did not generate any keys, an empty `ResultSet` object is returned."_ The behaviour to throw an exception violates the JDBC requirements of the API.

Comment: You might be missing the important detail that the `getGeneratedKeys` documentation talks about `Statement` (the object), not _statement_ (the statement text or specific execution of that statement text)

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the behaviour exhibited by MySQL Connector/J violates the requirements of the JDBC API and specification to return an empty result set if a `Statement` does not generate keys.

A `Statement` will generate keys if two conditions are met:

1. The appropriate prepare or execute method was called to allow generated keys (ie passing `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, or an array with column names or column indexes).
2. The statement text prepared or executed supports retrieval of generated keys (usually insert, sometimes also update, delete, merge, etc).

   Be aware that using the methods accepting column names or column indexes with a statement text that doesn't generate keys could result in an exception anyway, as those names or indexes likely won't be valid for that statement.

In all other situations, a `Statement` does not generate keys, and so `getGeneratedKeys()` should return an empty result set, as indicated by the [`Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) documentation:

> Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing
>   this `Statement` object. If this `Statement` object did not generate
>   any keys, an empty `ResultSet` object is returned.

And specifically, it only allows an exception under the following conditions:

> `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed `Statement`
>   `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` - if the JDBC driver does not support this method

If the JDBC specification would have required an exception to be thrown when the `Statement` wasn't prepared or executed using the appropriate methods (see point 1), that condition would have been listed in the reasons for throwing an exception.

This also matches behaviour in other parts of JDBC. For example in `DatabaseMetaData`, an implementation that doesn't support a certain type of metadata should return an empty result set instead of throwing an exception.